# Function defining the given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$0,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,\cdots$$

Wolfram alpha [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,...) that it is the number of distinct primes  in n. Does it have another closed form? (This is from an introductory book on fourier series)

Comment: For such questions it's always a good idea to consult the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: If you drop the initial $0$, you can find more possibilities in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C1) meaning that the next term can plausibly be $3$, $4$ or $5$

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on what you mean by closed form. It has a standard notation, $\omega(n)$, as you can see at the reference Theo gives. But if by a closed form you mean a way to calculate it that's easier than factoring $n$ and counting the number of primes you get, that would have to rate as exceedingly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I found the following formula
$$\large \omega(n)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\;\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{p^{r+1}}}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}{\;\;\;\sum_{k=0}^{\;p^{r+1}-1}\cos\left\lbrace 2k\pi \left(\frac{n+(p-j)p^{r}}{p^{r+1}}\right)\right\rbrace}$$

Where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers. A closely related one is

$$\large \Omega(n)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\;\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\frac{r}{p^{r+1}}}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}{\;\;\;\sum_{k=0}^{\;p^{r+1}-1}\cos\left\lbrace 2k\pi \left(\frac{n+(p-j)p^{r}}{p^{r+1}}\right)\right\rbrace}$$

They are useless... just factorize $n$ or... convert the to something useful!